# Meteor UI helper with Meteor.users

Tags: meteor

I have an app in which I'm using a template helper. I have the following code:

```
UI.registerHelper('ProfileNameByUserId', function(userid) {
  console.log('Userid: ' + userid);
  var user = Meteor.users.findOne({'_id': userid});
  console.log.log('User:' + user);
  return user.username 
});
```

I'm calling this in my template as follows:

```
{{#each getDocuments}}
   {{ProfileNameByUserId userid}}
{{/each}}
```

and in the template helper:

```
Template.documentsIndex.helpers({
  getDocuments: function () {
    return Documents.find({}, { sort: { createdAt: -1 }});
  }
});
```

The publish and subscribe are as follows:

```
Routes.route('/documents', {
  name: 'documents',
  subscriptions: function (params, queryParams) {
    this.register('documentsIndex', Meteor.subscribe('documents'));
  },
  action: function (params, queryParams) {
      .....
    });
  }
});

Meteor.publish('documents', function () {
   return Documents.find({})
});
```

I'm sure the userId is passed on, as a console.log statement shows the correct id. The issue is that the user is 'undefined' so it can't find the username.

I'm using SimpleSchema to define a users schema which looks as follows:

```
Users = Meteor.users;

Schema = {};

Schema.UserProfile = new SimpleSchema({
    firstName: {
        type: String,
        optional: true
    },
    lastName: {
        type: String,
        optional: true
    },
    gender: {
        type: String,
        allowedValues: ['Male', 'Female'],
        optional: true
    },
});

Schema.User = new SimpleSchema({
    username: {
        type: String,
        optional: true
    },
    emails: {
        type: Array,
        optional: true
    },
    "emails.$": {
        type: Object
    },
    "emails.$.address": {
        type: String,
        regEx: SimpleSchema.RegEx.Email
    },
    "emails.$.verified": {
        type: Boolean
    },
    createdAt: {
        type: Date,
        optional: true,
        denyUpdate: true,
        autoValue: function() {
            if (this.isInsert) {
                return new Date();
            }
        }
    },
    profile: {
        type: Schema.UserProfile,
        optional: true
    },
    services: {
        type: Object,
        optional: true,
        blackbox: true
    },
    roles: {
        type: [String],
        optional: true
    }
});

Meteor.users.attachSchema(Schema.User);
});
```

Replacing Meteor.users.findOne() in the template helper with Users.findOne() does not work either.

Any idea why user remains undefined?

Comment: I spotted a few things that might not work in your code, I can test it later in my project. For now take a look at my answer, it should work just fine

Comment: Edited the original question to include the schema and the pub/sub.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a publication and subscription for the users that you want to show.

In the most general case in which all users are published:

```
Meteor.publish('allUsers', function () {
    return Meteor.users.find();
});
```

Subscribe to this in your route and you will not have the user undefined in your helper.

Note that you should only publish the users that you need, but since I do not know you application structure I cannot give you a query for that.

Comment: This works indeed. I didn't realise I had to add another subscription for users as well. I thought Meteor.users was a special collection that was always published.

Comment: A fair misunderstanding.  If that was the case it would lead to security and scaling issues.